# How to pass data from fragment (.java file) to my fragment_layout.xml

Tags: android, android-fragments

My Problem: **I have a fragment which should display the time it gets from the database.**

In my `fragment.java` I get the data from the database and want to pass it to my `fragment_layout.xml` to show it.

(Every time the fragment is displayed, the actuall time is taken from the database)
I don't want to save the data for a long time, just want to show it.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: can you provide the code for your fragment and the layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put it to the *.xml file.

Your fragment.java file should have something like a reference to a TextView, which is defined i the fragment_layout.xml.

fragment_layout.xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myTimeTextView"
    android:... />
```

fragment.java:

```
TextView myTextView = view.FindViewById(Resource.layout.myTimeTextView);
```

You'll can change the Text like this:

```
myTextView.SetText(myTimeString);
```

"myTimeString" needs to be defined in a method, that is called even when the Fragment is shown (use an event).